# C - Pros/Cons of Enum-Indexed Arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, enums, indexing

In my experience, the real world rarely provides for indexes of nonnegative integers. Many things aren't even represented numerically. And many things with a numerically-represented index don't begin their indexes at 0. Why then are we still limited to integer-indexed arrays?

Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems like enum indexed arrays are often more appropriate than numerically-indexed arrays (as enums are often more accurate, "real-world" representations). While enums can often be translated into C-style array indices with relative ease...

```
enum Weekday = {
    SUNDAY,
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY
}

// hopefully C doesn't allow nonsequential enum values; else pray to God
// no one does something like setting Sunday = 4 and Saturday = 4096
int numberOfDays = Saturday-Sunday+1;

int hoursWorkedPerDay[numberOfDays];

hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)SUNDAY] = 0;
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)MONDAY] = 8;
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)TUESDAY] = 10;
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)WEDNESDAY] = 6;
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)THURSDAY] = 8;
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)FRIDAY] = 8;
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)SATURDAY] = 0;
```

...we are still required to maintain consistency between the number of enums and the size of the array (however, this isn't an awful solution because there's not a more valid integer mapping for "SUNDAY" than 0), and more importantly, anything that can be cast to an int could still be dropped into the index to manipulate the array:

```
// continued from above
void resetHours (void) {
    int i = 0;
    int hours = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<numberOfDays; i++) {
        hoursWorkedPerDay[hours] = i;
        // oops, should have been: "...[i] = hours;"
        // an enum-indexed implementation would have caught this
        // during compilation
    }
}
```

Furthermore, the entire conversion from enum to int is an entire layer of complexity that seems unnecessary.

Can someone please explain whether there is validity to enum-indices, and list some pros and cons to each approach? And perhaps why a feature so seemingly useful is missing from the C standard, if such information exists?

Comment: "hopefully C doesn't allow nonsequential enum values;" <- It soo does. (Also negative `enum` values.)

Comment: And thank God it does.  How would you implement an enumeration that is meant to be used as a bit mask otherwise?

Comment: This is another implementation of dictionary - translating property key (enumerated index) to property value (table value).

Comment: There's an integer promotion from enum to int in C++11 for unscoped enums with fixed underlying type (§4.6/4 conv.prom).

Comment: You should focus on either C or C++ or split it to 2 questions. There are different answers for each of the languages.

Comment: Hmmm, I doubt the closing of the question. It's not constructive to whine about missing C features, but promotes for better solutions in C++. But however ...

Comment: @pro_metedor, is there a dictionary in C indexed by Enum with array-esque performance? I'm under the impression that a key feature of dictionaries is hashing, which is unnecessary.

Comment: @EdS., I meant "hopefully..." in the context of the problem I was trying to solve--not that there aren't other valid uses.

Comment: @g-makulik, not whining, just trying to understand why it's not there--perhaps there's a better C-way of doing things?

Comment: @icepack, thanks for the heads up, I followed your advice and changed my title.

Comment: @weberc2 Don't worry, I just distended this as 'satirical' reason why your question was closed. About your doubts upon hashing, it's nothing else than computing integer hash values from non integers, enums **are** integers, just a typesafe subset. C just lacks on language capabilities as overriding operators and functions, which might affect the readability (and seemingly common convention) of other typesafe solutions (which are possible to do of course).

Comment: @g-makulik From what I understand, dictionaries aren't just "arrays with hashed indexes". First of all, I believe arrays require consecutive indexes--hashing doesn't provide this. Secondly, arrays have one value per key; I believe dictionaries may have more. However, I may be confusing general dictionaries with a specific implementation. Thoughts?

Comment: _because there's not a more valid integer mapping for "SUNDAY" than 0_ → you know, in many countries weeks start on Mondays. BTW, you may like this other language which allows to declare starting and ending indexes for arrays, it's called Pascal.

Comment: @weberc2 May be I was confusing thinking _'dictionaries'_ are the same as `std::map<>` in C++, though there's `std::multimap<>` that still provides mapping the key to multiple values. In C++ relying on a calculated hash value for particular key types completely refers on the capabilities of the key class. `std::map<>` and alike containers (e.g. `std::set<>`) just require the implementation of a less `operator<()` method for the key class. Having this implemented with (pre-)calculated hash values it might improve the efficiency and performance.

Comment: ninjalj, I've been doing separate side-by-side embedded projects in Ada and C. I believe Ada is similar to Pascal, and it has a lot of advantages that C doesn't; however, it also does everything in its power to throw compilation errors with meaningless messages. :p Anyway, I understand that some places start the week on different days. That doesn't seem to be particularly relevant, however...

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use the enum as index you should declare the integer values explicitly.

On the other hand I personally would prefer s.th. type safe (i.e. without the ugly cast, that might even not be necessary), like:

```
std::map<Weekday,int> hoursWorkedPerDay;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sunday =0 //by default, if you won't mention explicit value then it would take 0
```

and `Saturday = 6 // as in your example`

so

```
int numberOfDays = Saturday-Sunday; // which is 6 

int hoursWorkedPerDay[numberOfDays];
```

array will have only 6 places to hold the value.

```
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)SUNDAY] = 0;
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)MONDAY] = 8;
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)TUESDAY] = 10;
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)WEDNESDAY] = 6;
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)THURSDAY] = 8;
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)FRIDAY] = 8;
hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)SATURDAY] = 0;
```

accessing out of array index (which is 6) is undefined behaviour

Comment: I did exactly this in my example...

Comment: read the last line of my answer .. you did exactly that's why it's undefined behaviour

Comment: Where did I try to access an index greater than 6? Furthermore, index out of bounds behavior wasn't exactly my point, but it does go to show that an enum-indexed array wouldn't have to worry about that.

Comment: you are not seeing my answer properly. you have created array of size 6 so you can't access a[6], because 5 is the last valid index and after that accessing is undefined behaviour. I think you understand

Comment: I agree. Please show me where I tried to access array[6], because I really am not seeing it.

Comment: `hoursWorkedPerDay[(int)SATURDAY] = 0;`  //what does this line mean ? Sateurady is 6 right ?

Comment: Okay, I understand your point now; however, it is irrelevant to the discussion. I'll correct my code.